# Linux: error getting credentials - err: docker-credential-desktop.exe resolves to executable in current directory (./docker-credential-desktop.exe)

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am on Linux (wsl), not Docker Desktop for Windows!

However, I've used vscode with Docker plugin from Microsoft enabled to connect to that machine via SSH.

And now when I'm doing docker compose up, this pops. Seems that has screwed my linux machine somehow.

I've tried apt-get install --reinstall and wsl --shutdown (reboot vm) to no avail.

What can I do to fix it?